# Windows firewall suddenly blocking SMTP connection over VPN

Tags: windows-firewall

For years, everything has been just fine. I have an always on VPN and have had no problems.

Them a few days ago, there was a Windows update. Since then, attempts to send email meet with SMTP connection timeout, both for my own server and for Gmail, and using two different email clients (both of which have been configured & working for years, and I have not changed them).

If I disable either the VPN or the Windows firewall, I can send email (I can still always fetch over IMAP).

I want to continue to use the VPN, and they tell me that they have changed nothing, so, how do I go about  configuring the Windows Firewall to allow STMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Create an Outbound Port Deny Rule for Windows Firewall](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/creating-an-outbound-port-deny-rule-for-windows-firewall-windows-2008/). It says it's for Windows 2008, but it worked for me on Windows 10, Home edition.

Copied the solution from mentioned website:

> 1. Launch Windows Firewall with Advanced Security by clicking on Start > Administrative Tools > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.
> 2. Select Outbound Rules in the left pane and click New Rule.
> 3. The New Outbound Rule Wizard launches. Select Port and click Next.
> 4. This screen is to determine if this rule applies to TCP or UDP protocol and all ports or specific port(s). Select either TCP or UDP and then either select all ports or select “Specific local ports:” and fill in the port(s) separating them with a comma if necessary. Click Next to continue.
> 5. Since this is for an allow rule you will need to select weather to allow this traffic for all connections (secure and insecure) or only if the connection is secure. If you require the connection to be secure you can also specify if it also requires Encryption or if it overrides block rules. Click Next to continue.
> 6. On this screen you can select which profiles the rule applies to. Domain applies when the inbound connection is coming from a computer within the domain. Private applies when the inbound connection is coming from a source that has selected Private for it’s profile. Public applies to all connections coming from a source whose profile is set to Public. You can select one, two or all three. Click Next to continue.
> 7. This is the screen were you will give the rule a name and any description you would like to specify. Click Finish to create the rule and go back to the main screen.

Juts create a new outbound rule for port 465 (SSL) (or port 587, eventually port 25 - not recommended, as appropriate) and allow outgoing traffic. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution in Windows 10 Pro:

1. Open Windows Defender Security Center
2. Go to Virus & Threat protection settings.
3. Select Exclusions
4. Select Add or remove exclusions
5. Select Add an exclusion and add your VPN client software

Note: Most VPN clients use ports 500 and 4500 UDP, and port 1723 for TCP. If these don’t work, add a new rule to allow them in Windows Firewall Advanced settings.

Comment: I don't see a `Windows Defender Security Center`, just `Windows Defender`, an, in that, I don't see `Virus & Threat protection settings` - what am I missing? :-(

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Widnwos 10 Home. I guess your suggestion is for Pro. I have upvoted it a sit could help others n future (you might want to edit it & mention Pro), I solved the problem & will post an answer. Thanks for your help